# SharePoint - Unable to complete this operation. Please contact your administrator

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

When I try and save something to my list in SharePoint I get the following error:

```
Unable to complete this operation.  Please contact your administrator.
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String   bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage) 
    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.PutFile(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebRelativeUrl, Object varFile, PutFileOpt PutFileOpt, String bstrCreatedBy, String bstrModifiedBy, Int32 iCreatedByID, Int32 iModifiedByID, Object varTimeCreated, Object varTimeLastModified, Object varProperties, String bstrCheckinComment, UInt32& pdwVirusCheckStatus, String& pVirusCheckMessage)
```

A quick google says it may be a problem with disk space on the Database. I have checked my server and the smallest amount of space left on any of the drives is ~4GB. The file size is 1MB. I have checked the database and the data file is on unrestricted growth.

Any ideas?

Comment: how big are the data files in your database? are they SQL server express or SQL Server std?

Comment: Can this question be migrated to serverfault?

Comment: Were you using the API or object model? ie were you programming this, or was this a problem for normal in-the-browser use of SharePoint? If the former, could you include some code? This seems familiar, and I'm curious as to what circumstances this happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was the transaction log was full preventing any changes. The data file was fine.